# Get random not repeating value from array

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I have method called getRandomCar which is executed via NSTimer for 4 seconds. This method have an array like  this

```
NSArray *cars = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mercedes", @"Opel", @"Ford", @"Mazda", nil];
```

The idea is when getRandomCar method is called the returned value to be different from the last returned i.e

```
Mescedes Opel Mercedes Mazda Ford Opel etc..
```

not

```
Mercedes Mercedes Mazda Opel Opel etc...
```

I have tried this but with no luck.

```
NSString *car = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", 
                           [carsArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [carsArray count]]];

    if ([self.tmpCar isEqualToString:car]) 
    {
        car = [carsArray lastObject];
    }

    [self settmpCar:playerName];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
NSArray *carsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mercedes", @"Opel", @"Ford", @"Mazda", nil];

NSMutableString *car = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *lastCar = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[lastCar setString:@"XXX"];

do {


    [car setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
            [carsArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [carsArray count]]]];
}
while ([lastCar isEqualToString:car]);
[lastCar setString:car];
```

Comment: hmmm.. its weird, let me try another solution, Ill be back in 5 min :)

Comment: Your algorithm is not working correcrtly if array is of two objects. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Why are you using mutable strings?  Just use references to the strings in the array and use simple assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to remember the index of the last car. And when you generate a random number check if it's equal to the previous and, if so, generate another number. Sample code:

```
int test;
int lastValue;
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    test = arc4random() % 10;
    if (test == lastValue) {
        while (test == lastValue) {
            test = arc4random();
            NSLog(@"in While loop");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%i", test);
    }
    lastValue = test;
}
```

Hope it helps

**edit**

Decided to add the code for you:

```
NSArray *cars = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mercedes", @"Opel", @"Ford", @"Mazda", nil];
int test;
int lastValue;
for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
    test = arc4random() % [cars count];
    if (test == lastValue) {
        while (test == lastValue) {
            test = arc4random();
        }
    } else {
        NSString *car = [cars objectAtIndex:test];
        lastValue = test;
    }
}
```

that will make 20 random non-repeatable cars

Answer (score 0):

You can use another array to hold the cars that have already been picked up before.  In the following example, once you exhaust the entire `carsArray`, method `GetCar` will return `nil`.  Note that this may not be the most efficient way, but for a small size of `carsArray` it should work fine.

At the class level:

```
NSMutableArray *prevCars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Your method:

```
-(NSString*) GetCar {

    if([prevCars count] == [carsArray count])
        return nil;

    NSMutableString *car = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    do {
        [car setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
            [carsArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [carsArray count]]]];
    }
    while ([InArray:prevCars value:car])

    [prevCars addObject:car];

    return car;
}
```

And then:

```
-(BOOL)InArray:(NSArray *)arr value:(NSString *)val {

    for (id Elem in arr) {
        if([val isEqualToString:(NSString*)val])
            return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Of course, make sure to free the memory when you're done.